# multi-product delivery optimization problem : simplify model and constraints

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to solve the following problem :

We have different unique products that needs to be deliver to clients (1 product = 1 client).
We have several factories, some products can only be produce by a factory.
A product needs 10 days to be constructed in a factory.
Then I have several vehicles to deliver the products.
A vehicle can take several products for a delivery.
It is also possible to store a finished product in an other factory than where it was produced.

The goal is to reduce delivery fees.

For example it can be good to transfer a product from a store to another in order to make a grouped delivery if two clients are close from a factory.

I used the following model :

Sets are :
T for time

I for factories

J for products (or client)

K for vehicles

(and V are the nodes, so V = I union J)

My decisions variable are :
[image] : 1 if product j is product in factory i at time t

[image] : 1 if product j in on board on vehicle k at time t and does the route i1 -> i2 (i1 and i2 in V)

[image] : 1 if vehicle k makes the route i1 -> i2 at time t

[image] : 1 if vehicle k visits node i at time t. (i in V)

The function to minimize is :
[image] (c[i1][i2] is the cost of route i1 -> i2)

And the constraints are :

We need to product a product only once
[image]

We need to deliver each product
[image]

Coherence of routing :
[image]
[image]

10 days after production before delivery
[image]

There is a limit date for delivery for each product
[image]

A product can only be on board of a vehicle
[image]

And the last constraint that is a problem for me : we can only transport a product from where is it placed. So I use the following constraint that means that to leave i1 the product must have been producted in i1 or have arrived in i1 before.

[image]

Problem is this is very very slow. It takes several minutes for 5 clients and 2 factories (T_max = 45).

I need to find a way to have a descent speed algorithm in production where I'll have ap 30/40 clients, 5 factories and T_max = 90.

Would you have any idea how to fasten the algorithm ? It is this last constraints that leads to a slow optimization.

Maybe my modelization is wrong and there is a simpler way to do it.

Or I think we can maybe simplify this last constraint, adding for exemple another decision variable, but I don't find a solution to do that.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: May be better to ask here: https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh yes ! Will ask there, thank's !